# Use mercurius, fastify with typegraphql make an error

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, fastify, typegraphql

I am trying to use typegraphql with mercurius and fastify I have copied this intergration from mercurius documentaion, when I add the built schema to mercurius it show me an error in this way:

[image]

When I remove it, the error disappear

[image]

This is the error message shown:

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginCallback<MercuriusOptions, Server>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.
> Type 'GraphQLSchema' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | GraphQLSchema | undefined'.
> Type 'GraphQLSchema' is missing the following properties from type 'GraphQLSchema': description, getImplementations, isSubType
> Overload 2 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginAsync<MercuriusOptions, Server>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'typeof mercurius' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FastifyPluginAsync<MercuriusOptions, Server>'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
> Overload 3 of 3, '(plugin: FastifyPluginCallback<MercuriusOptions, Server> | FastifyPluginAsync<MercuriusOptions, Server> | Promise<...> | Promise<...>, opts?: FastifyRegisterOptions<...> | undefined): FastifyInstance<...> & PromiseLike<...>', gave the following error.
> Type 'GraphQLSchema' is not assignable to type 'string | string[] | GraphQLSchema | undefined'.

Comment: It seems a conflict issue. what module version do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had to downgrade `graphql` packages from version 6 to 4 because the mercurius does not support graphql 6 until now.